# I want to compress images before upload to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to upload 5 images into database and to temp files, it is uploading to the database but in temp files they do not appear because of images sizes, so I want to compress and upload them. How I do that?

```
$query= mysqli_query($con,"select max(id) as pid from products");
         $result=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
         $product_id=$result['pid']+1;
         $dir="images/product_images/$product_id";

    if(!is_dir($dir)){
            mkdir("images/product_images/".$product_id);
        }
    
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["productimage1"]["temp_name"],"images/product_images/$product_id/".$_FILES["productimage1"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["productimage2"]["temp_name"],"images/product_images/$product_id/".$_FILES["productimage2"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["productimage3"]["temp_name"],"images/product_images/$product_id/".$_FILES["productimage3"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["productimage4"]["temp_name"],"images/product_images/$product_id/".$_FILES["productimage4"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["productimage5"]["temp_name"],"images/product_images/$product_id/".$_FILES["productimage5"]["name"]);
```

Comment: You have not attached the query that is responsible for entering the information into the database. Looks like you're just saving the file to another folder.
Note that mysql_query is no longer used

Comment: Eden Moshe , can you give me a correct code for it.please

Comment: See for instance https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick

Comment: Who can give me a correct code for my above work ? Please help me somebody,my images are uploading to database but they are not appear in temp files,so i want to reduce size of 5 images and to upload ...HELP HELP HELP

Comment: You're not going to have much success compressing JPEG image files - they're already compressed. Other formats you might compress a bit, or you might not. Better to increase the allowed upload size

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To group the image size see this [guide](https://dev.to/niick007/how-to-compress-image-size-without-losing-quality-in-php-4d2h)

As detailed in the link:
Resizing the image directly affects its quality.
In our case we would like to change the image format to jpeg if it is not.

```
   $info = getimagesize($source_url);
    if ($ info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
       $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
    }
```

We will then create the image and change its quality.
The lower the length, the less weight you will have, but the lower the resolution.

```
 imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
```

When:

source_url: It is the temporary location in our case of file upload.

destination_url: It is the destination path where we want to upload our

$quality - Image quality in percent.

Comment: Can you edit my code according to my question? It's a great help for me..

Comment: No.
stackoverflow is not a code requesting system.
Here we can help you understand where the problem is in your code and suggest solutions not to write code for you.

Comment: Thank You Very Much Sir .....I solve My Problem ...Can i compress more these images ? when i first upload it was 4mb sized and now it is 1.2mb ...Can i compress more ?